# Am I counting the beat on my 4/4 meter correctly or not?

Tags: rhythm, time-signatures, beats

I got a rhythm pattern in 4/4 time signature where I'm little confuse with the rest notes while counting. I have made my count as below given picture where you can see count are made in red text.
[image]

I played and it sounds favorable and seems like each beat note are getting there count which they use to hold. Any way please make me confirm by telling how it's fine if I didn't made mistake and if I made mistake tell me. I would love to hear the reason no matter correct or wrong. I just need solid reason of this beat count which I am little unsure of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's being strummed on guitar. Yes, the rhythm, is written properly - not sure why there's a little dot after the a of beat 3, 1st bar.

On guitar, it's easier to play ghost strums where there are no chords sounding. It keeps the rhythmic pattern of the strumming hand/arm going. Far better than just stopping, and starting again at the next strum.

To 'play' the rests, just release the pressure of the fretting fingers, in the same way as you do with the chords marked with 'x'.

There's nothing wrong with counting the rests in the same '2e&a' way. Just because it's a rest doesn't mean it's different from a note - both have counting values!

Comment: It's not written by me. Jody fisher whom I would love to give credit as he is the author who wrote this all. From here [Rhythm_Guitar](http://noty-bratstvo.org/sites/default/files/gitara-Rhythm_Guitar.pdf) I counted it with my own knowledge so, was little unsure but thanks for proving!

Comment: '2e&a' ? Won't that work as above '2 +a' ?

Comment: Yes, of course. But the point in counting (out loud if you want) is to keep the rhythm going, so count the same bits for every beat, it's just easier keeping time and keeping count.